# Reading and writing to a local sqlite database from a Chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome, storage

Is it possible to read and write to a local sqlite file from a chrome packaged app? I currently already read and write to a json file with app data that is locally stored on the harddrive but I also want to be able to do this with a sqlite database. I need it to be local and not on drive since I will interact with it from other (non chrome) processes as well. And even loading the file from drive (using sync filesystem instead of filesystem), I have no clue how to go about accessing a sqlite file

Comment: can you elaborate this: "I need it to be local and not on drive"? As far as I've understood, you need your Chrome app to talk to SQLite database file which will be stored on the system on the location set by the you. Have I understood correctly?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite support for Chrome Packaged Apps would be great. After all, Chrome on the desktop and on Android supports it.

But it doesn't. There is an open issue for it - join in!

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339579